# Converting -moz-radial-gradient to all other supporting browsers

Tags: css, wordpress, firefox, gradient

```
.gradient {
background: -moz-radial-gradient(right bottom , circle farthest-corner, #CDCFD1 20%,     #696C71 70%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
```

I want to take that rule and apply it to all of the browsers that support a linear gradient. Could someone tell me what the code would look like in order to support the above radial gradient in all other browser that support it, i.e. chrome, internet explorer, safari etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well i don't understand why, because my specific question, 110% CANNOT be answered by using Google, at least not using the wording i've entered. I want to convert EXISTING gradients to all other supported browsers, the link you gave me doesn't help solve my problem. Your down vote, along with the other 3 are totally unwarranted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot make the gradient compatible with all browsers in a single line of code..you have to add more compatible lines for different browsers..try this..

```
background: rgb(105,108,113); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(105,108,113,1) 30%, rgba(205,207,209,1) 81%, rgba(205,207,209,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(30%,rgba(105,108,113,1)), color-stop(81%,rgba(205,207,209,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(205,207,209,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(105,108,113,1) 30%,rgba(205,207,209,1) 81%,rgba(205,207,209,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(105,108,113,1) 30%,rgba(205,207,209,1) 81%,rgba(205,207,209,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(105,108,113,1) 30%,rgba(205,207,209,1) 81%,rgba(205,207,209,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(105,108,113,1) 30%,rgba(205,207,209,1) 81%,rgba(205,207,209,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#696c71', endColorstr='#cdcfd1',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't help. I want to convert an existing gradient to be compatible in all browsers, this link simply allows me to make a new gradient, which i do not want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://css3please.com/

And this could be helpful, too: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't help. I want to convert an existing gradient to be compatible in all browsers, this link simply allows me to make a new gradient, which i do not want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://gradients.glrzad.com/ or http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ for supporting in all browser.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't help. I want to convert an existing gradient to be compatible in all browsers, this link simply allows me to make a new gradient, which i do not want to do.

Comment: @Nikki Mather u can add using -moz-linear-gradient webkit-linear-gradient and o-linear-gradient to make compatible in all browser..just google it